# Android, getResources for string array won't work

Tags: android, arrays, resources

I try to follow the example on the Andoid developers [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) in order to implement a string array from string resoirces. It doesn't work.
The following line of code in my `MainActivity`(right at the top of the class) is throwing an runtime exception error:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   Resources res = getResources();
   String[] fortuneStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.fortuneStringArray);
...
```

I checked everything but I do not know how else to debug. Any help?
Thanks.

**1. Edit**

here is my `string.xml`

```
<resources>
  <string-array name = "fortuneStringArray">
    <item>blabla1</item>
    <item>blabla2</item>
    <item>blabla3</item>
    <item>blabla4</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: In which method of MainActivity you have this? And what is the cause shown in the exception?

Comment: Can you post whole exception?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the stack trace, please post it. Note that if these lines are initializers in your class, instead of local variables in a method, that's probably your problem -- you cannot call `getResources()` until inside `onCreate()` or at later points in the life of your activity.